# Html + pure css alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to obtain this result with pure html/css
I've tried to use a flexbox with a .row and two .col inside and then another div inside the col to show the card. But I've some problems with the overlapping of the divs and with the height of divs(in order to have square images, no matter of the screen size). What's the best solution to obtain the image's result?

Thanks in advance

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <div class='round-container'>
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <div class='round-container'>
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <div class='round-container'>
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <div class='round-container'>
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

------------ css --------
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

.col {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  max-height: 45px;
}

.round-container {
   margin: 20px;
   background: #efefef;
   border-radius: 99999px;
}

i.material-icons {
   display: block;
}
```

[image: screen]

Comment: Please share the code you have so far. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I've added my code

Comment: @MarcoBidoli Just making sure I understand your problem. The CSS uses rounded corners and you'd like it to be square instead of rounded, and all squares to have the same size. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: The rounded corners are not the problem, but yes, I need all divs with a square size and equidistant one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vertical padding of `100%` on a non-flex-child to make the height proportional to the width, then position an element inside of it with the contents you want.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

.col {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - .5em);
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.round-container {
  background: #efefef;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

i.material-icons {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='round-container'>
      <div class="inner">
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='round-container'>
      <div class="inner">
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='round-container'>
      <div class="inner">
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    <div class='round-container'>
      <div class="inner">
        <i class='material-icons'>android</i>
        <a href='homepage.php?page=myevents'>My events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```